# ssh Unknown error IPv6 windows10

Tags: windows, ssh, ipv6

I need to ssh a device from LAN.

I've been able to do so in IPv4 in linux and windows10 but for IPv6, it only worked in linux.
[image]

ipconfig PC LAN:

[image: ipconfig]
This is the error I got in windows10:

```
ssh -vvv  Admin@fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/SST/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1 [fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10051, io:000002C418562F50
debug1: connect to address fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1 port 22: Unknown error
ssh: connect to host fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1 port 22: Unknown error
```

from the wireshark capture, the icmpv6 was sent correctly:
[image]
but it was'nt created correctly in windows (prefix 128 instead of 64)
[image]
and when I added a route manually `netsh interface ipv6 add fdaa:bbcc:ddee::/64  "Ethernet" fe80:347e:1e96:7936:a9ee` it worked
so it's basically a problem with routing, but why this problem is  caused in windows10 ?

Comment: What does ping say about the address?
Probably no difference but you could try `ssh -vv  Admin@[fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1]`

Comment: with ping [fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1] -> all packets were lost, ssh -vv  Admin@[fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1] same output as ssh -vv  Admin@fdaa:bbcc:ddee::1

Comment: can you ping your link local address? or can you see the windows host from your linux machine in `ip -6 nei` Are they on the same LAN?

Comment: yes, I can ping the LLA address, you'll find it in the problem description above

Comment: Check the error log of sshd on the target machine.

Comment: How can I check  error log of sshd via windows ?

Comment: You do not have any ping output in the description, This is an issue with client not able to connect to the server. And it is not denied or timed out, but rather unknown, which makes me suspect configuration issues of the IP stack on the client.

Comment: in fact, when a connect a PC LAN with linux, the ULA address that he has is fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:649b:bd08:1258:c7f0/64 (prefix 64) while in windows it's fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:347e:1e96:7936:a9ee/128 (prefix 128)

Comment: Still no output from ping in the question, I think that would show any error message more clearly. (also please use text when possible, not images) You are correct you should have a `On-link` line in your route output.

Comment: Based on prefix 128 instead of 64 in your system, it means your windows didn't get RA(router advertisement) correctly. Actually you found the problem and let's find solution in RA in your network.

Comment: okey, how can I know why windows didn't receine an RA, knowing that the ICMPv6 option (RA) was sent correctly?